Why don't CD pipelines build with secrets embedded?
I'm working on a large Go project that needs various API keys, we have a action triggered on push that builds the server binary and uploads that to a GCP instance.  A systemd service that calls the binary with flags for each of the API keys is also uploaded(though a .env file could also be used functionally the same).  I think a lot of CI/CD pipelines do something similar, why not just embed the secrets in the binary itself at that point though?  (Through ldflags or sed or something)

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/409856/how-can-i-protect-sensitive-information-inside-a-binary

@RuiJarimba That's for an app distributed to a client.  What I'm talking about is purely server side.

have you read the answers in that post?

@RuiJarimba Yes, I don't see how any of them are applicable.  The secrets aren't in version control- and the built binary isn't anywhere except on the server being deployed to and the, in my case, Github build server.

I suggest you re-read this answer.

@RuiJarimba The only thing I see there is "Tokens can and do change" but I don't see rebuilding the binary and reuploading it as significantly different from rebuilding a .env file, reuploading it, and restarting the server.  Though its possible that .env's could be read everytime they're needed rather than just on server start- but I've never seen people actually do that

There are a few reasons why this isn't common, from my experience. This isn't an exhaustive list, but here are a couple:

Separation of Concerns - Embedding secrets in your binary complicates key management and environment configuration. Ex: if you need to rotate a key, you’d have to rebuild and redeploy the binary. Similarly, managing different environments (dev/stg/prd) becomes difficult, as you'd need separate binaries for each, with their respective secrets embedded. Keeping secrets external allows for easier updates and environment separation without touching your app code.
Security Risks - If someone gains access to your binary, they can potentially use it to interact with your systems directly, without needing to hunt for or extract the embedded secrets.




That's true I hadn't considered that because I was planning for any server management to only be done through pipelines.  As for the different environments, that's already handled by a calling pipeline passing the separate secrets and server IDs to the build/deployment action.


That's true I guess, but at least for my usecase, either way the pipeline uses SCP to upload both the generated .env and binary- then the pipeline ends.  So without either changing the pipeline to output the binary or already having access to the server that would be impossible.


